# how to delete a style that associated to a layer?

Tags: geoserver, rest

I want to apply a style to a layer by rest.at the first time everything is ok. But when I change the content of the sld file in the style folder mannually,it doesn't apply to the layer. I want a way to do  this by rest,not by submit the style through the style editor in geoserver.and How can I remove binding of astyle from a layer?

Answer (score 2):

Styles are cached in memory.
If you change them manually on disk GeoServer will not reload automatically.

I would suggest to simply replace the original style, forcing a configuration reload is probably too intrusive (and won't scale).

Simone.